# T-SQL get beginning of week date

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I would like to query the Marketing Cloud _opens table to find any opens in the last 7 days but from the beginning of that given day.

Using the following will get the last 7 days relative to the current time:

```
select SubscriberKey, EventDate
from _opens
where EventDate => (s.EventDate > getdate()-7)
```

*pseudo code fyi*

So as of now (2018-08-06 15:37:00) it will go back to 2018-07-31 15:37:00 but I want the beginning of the day so its 2018-07-31 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pulling only date from getdate() and then adding the 0 time to it. Something like below:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, EventDate
FROM _Open
WHERE EventDate >= convert(char(14),DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE() ),121) +'00:00'
```

Comment: A simple Convert(Date,[Date field]) will remove the time part of a date column.

Comment: Could you give a quick explanation of what the 121 does at the end?

Comment: The 121 is the 'style' of the function. Here is more info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017